# Servlet Exception java.io.filenotfoundexception inputstream

Tags: java, servlets

I have an exception thrown when launching the servelt doPost java.io.filenotfoundexception http://intssneip01.ppmail.ppservices.axa-tech.intraxa:5510/ws/fr-eda-pushevent-v1-vs 
It occurs on the line inputstream getInputStream, here is the code:

String name = "admin";
            String password = "admin";

```
        String authString = name + ":" + password;
        System.out.println("auth string: " + authString);
        byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
        String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
        System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);

        URL url = new URL(backUrl);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);

        String line = "";
          StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
          BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()) );
          while((line = input.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(line);
          input.close();
```

Comment: A call to `getInputStream()` can throw a `FileNotFoundException` if the remore server responds with a "404 Not Found".  Check the URL you are attempting to fetch.  If this doesn't give you any clues, show us the stacktace.

Comment: this is what happens when ic put the url in browser: 
<faultstring>Mediator encountered an error:Resources for the endpoint URI not found. Endpoint URI: / while executing operation:null service:fr-eda-pushevent-v1-vs at time:2:09:51 PM on date:Nov 30, 2017. The client ip was:null. The current user:Default. The consumer application:null</faultstring>

Comment: Yup.  That tends to support what I said.

Comment: This means the problem is on the URL itself ?

Comment: That's what I think.